# Encoding data of mixed type?

Tags: python

I've got an array as follows:

```
row = [u'Arun DC', 4.0, 34.0, 76.0, 223.52941176470588, u'yes', 0.0, '', '', '', '', u'yes', '', u'yes', u'yes', u'yes', u'no', u'\xa37.50 - \xa310 not clear what this is for', u'\xa37.50 - \xa310 not clear what this is for', '', u'\xa37.50 - \xa310 not clear what this is for', u'\xa37.50 - \xa310 not clear what this is for', '', '', '', '', u'no water on sites', '', u'1st years rent free', '']
```

I want to write it out to a CSV file, but I get the following error:

```
writer.writerow(row)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So I have tried encoding it first, but that gives me an error, because I can't encode the float items:

```
writer.writerow([i.encode('latin-1') for i in row])
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Any thoughts on a neat way to get around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[x.encode('latin-1') if isinstance(x, unicode) else x
 for x in row]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[i.encode('latin-1') if isinstance(i, unicode) else i for i in row]
```

Comment: yeah, but that filters out the numbers entirely.

Comment: Good point, updated to use ternary if rather than the list comprehension's one.

Comment: Now we have 2 answers which differ each other by one variable name.

Answer (score 1):

```
[('%s'%a).encode('latin-1') for a in row]
```

returns a list of strings. You could use it to write out to CSV.